# How to install Gamooga server on centOS?

Tags: centos, packages, lua

I'm trying to run [Gamooga](http://www.gamooga.com/dev/docs/sdk.html#installation-on-linux) server on my centOS box, but unfortunately there are some required packages which is not available for centOS (at least I couldn't find them).
The required packages are

1. liblua5.1-0
2. liblua5.1-0-dev

If anyone could tell me how to get it running, I would be greatly grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently package libua is provided by:

```
lua-5.1.4-4.1.el6.x86_64 : Powerful light-weight programming language
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Other       : liblua-5.1.so()(64bit)
```

Have you trying to install this or lua-static package??